# How to get last 12 months values when some months have no records in the table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a table which has PartNumberKey and Depot_ID as composite primary key. It returns the following data -

[image]

The requirement is to add the month columns for which there is no row with 0 as Total for last 12 months (i.e from 2018-11 to 2018-12). The expected output should be:

[image]

Kindly help me with the query formation?

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql).

Comment: Also please post sample data as tabular or insert statements, not screen shots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a table of numbers, which you then use with `dateadd` to make a table of months. Then you can `left join` it.

If you don’t have a table of numbers, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` on a large enough table.

```
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(month, @month1, @month2)+1)
    DATEADD(month, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) -1, @month1) AS TheMonth
    FROM dbo.MyTable
```

You’ll also need your list of PartNumberKey and Depot_ID values.

```
DECLARE @month1 date = ‘20171201’, @month2 date = ‘20181101’; -- the semicolon is important!!
WITH months as (
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(month, @month1, @month2)+1)
    DATEADD(month, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) -1, @month1) AS TheMonth
    FROM dbo.MyTable
),
PartsDepots as (
    SELECT DISTINCT PartNumberKey, Depot_ID
    FROM dbo.MyTable
)
SELECT pd.PartNumberKey, pd.Depot_ID, m.TheMonth, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM months m
CROSS JOIN PartsDepots pd 
LEFT JOIN dbo.MyTable t
    ON t.TheDate >= m.TheMonth
    AND t.TheDate < DATEADD(month,1,m.TheMonth)
    AND t.PartNumberKey = pd.PartNumberKey
    AND t.Depot_ID = pd.Depot_ID
GROUP BY t.TheMonth, pd.PartNumberKey, pd.Depot_ID
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this table:

```
CREATE TABLE #ProductData
(
  PartNumberKey char(5),
  Depot_ID char(2),
  [Month] char(7),
  Total int,
  CONSTRAINT PK_PD PRIMARY KEY (PartNumberKey, Depot_ID)
);

INSERT #ProductData VALUES('1538A','2B','2018-02',17),
                          ('1538B','2A','2017-12',23);
```

An interesting problem because you need to both determine missing months and also fill in the missing key/ID combos for those missing months.

```
DECLARE @months    int  = 12, -- up to 100
        @thismonth date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()),1);

;WITH m AS
(
  SELECT m = 1 UNION ALL SELECT m + 1 FROM m WHERE m < @months
),
months(m) AS
(
  SELECT CONVERT(char(7), DATEADD(MONTH, 1-m, @thismonth))
  FROM m
),
keypairs AS
(
  SELECT PartNumberKey, Depot_ID
    FROM #ProductData
    WHERE [Month] >= CONVERT(char(7), DATEADD(MONTH, -11, @thismonth), 120)
    GROUP BY PartNumberKey, Depot_ID
)
SELECT m.m, p.PartNumberKey, p.Depot_ID, COALESCE(pd.Total,0)
  FROM months AS m
  CROSS JOIN keypairs AS p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #ProductData AS pd
    ON p.PartNumberKey = pd.PartNumberKey
   AND p.Depot_ID = pd.Depot_ID
   AND m.m = pd.[Month]
ORDER BY p.PartNumberKey, p.Depot_ID, m.m;
```

Comment: Ah - I was typing too...